# How do I remove the notification "You have granted access to your account to xxxxxxxx@gmail.com"?

Tags: security, permissions, gmail

I have a primary GMail mail account (e.g.; Private@gmail.com) which I use to communicate with my close friends and family members, to which my Youtube account with a lot of personal and ideological videos are tied up (As far as I know, anyone can visit my channel by simply visiting www.youtube.com/user/Private). I have another account (e.g.; Public@gmail.com) for giving any people who want my mail address. I forwarded incoming mails Public@gmail.com to Private@gmail.com, so that I don't need to check it very often.

Today, during a job interview, I had to login "Public" to send a file, and people were looking at my screen. It became a stressful situation when that message appeared. I had a very difficult time trying to hide it.

I understand that this is required for the security of average user, but isn't there a way of completely hiding it? How do I tell GMail that I can handle my own security?

[image]

Comment: Have you recently made a change to the delegation settings?

Comment: @TomRuh No, I haven't made any settings change on neither of my accounts. This message has been appearing every time I login to Private for years. I have ignored it since this situation happened today.

Comment: According to this article, it should be a temporary notice. [Gmail Help](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/1355565?hl=en)

Comment: That's odd. I have several accounts forwarding to my main account and none of them show that message. The only way I could get a similar thing to appear is to turn on "delegation", and even then the message said it would go away in 7 days. *How* are you forwarding your messages? Perhaps this is a leftover from an old way of Gmail doing this; disconnecting and reconnecting your accounts might help.

Comment: @ale This is not for forwarding, this is for granting access to account, see settings →  Accounts and Import → Grant access to your account.